extract the value after a specific text that occurs multiple times
lets say I have a table



id
name




1
[{"name":"Herman"},{"name":"Iwan"]



and I would like to extract all the value.
the expected result should be in 2 rows,



id
name




1
Herman


1
Iwan



I have tried using substring,
right((SUBSTRING(col, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('"name":"', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(LEFT(col, 
CHARINDEX ('"name":"', col))) - LEN(RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('"},{"', col))) - 1)),len((SUBSTRING(col, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('"name":"', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(LEFT(col, 
CHARINDEX ('"name":"', col))) - LEN(RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('"},{"', col))) - 1)))-7)

but it will only return the first name which is Herman, I would like to have it return as many name as it is in the string.

SELECT 
    p.id,
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.name') AS name
FROM 
    people p
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(p.name)

The above should work for you.

it does not work on databricks/spark - would you mind sharing how does it work?

PostgreSQL:
SELECT
id,
json_array_elements_text(name::json->'name') AS name
FROM
your_table;
JSON data:
SELECT
id,
value AS name
FROM
your_table
CROSS APPLY
OPENJSON(name)
WITH (
name NVARCHAR(100) '$.name'
);

Above have SQL and jason data

thanks for the explaination but apparently sparksql does not support openjson and i could not find similar function that can replace it

Spark SQL have built-in JSON function.
First, ensure that you have imported the necessary libraries:
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JSONParsing").getOrCreate()

Create a DataFrame
JSON array:
import spark.implicits._
// Sample data
val data = Seq(
(1, """[{"name":"Herman"},{"name":"Iwan"}]""")
).toDF("id", "name")
// Parse the JSON array and explode it into individual rows
val parsedDF = data.withColumn("name", explode(from_json($"name", ArrayType(MapType(StringType, StringType)))))
.select($"id", $"name".getItem("name").as("name"))
parsedDF.show()

Hope this helps

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
